# Как добавить в одно поле более одного предмета DatagridView?

Tags: c#

Всем добрый день.Как можно добавить в одно поле несколько значений не создавая новой линии.Вот к примеру

```
№     Id   Name
1     255  test1
2     100  test2
```

Как к полю 255 дописать еще одно значение через запятую.К примеру 255,434.Пробывал через цикл for но там добавляеться новая строка.

Вот допустим есть такой код:

```
int [] array = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,5,5,3,423,43,65,5,3,2};
    Random s = new Random();

    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
        {
            int rand = s.Next(0,10);
            for(int k=0;k<rand;k++)
            {
                Data_test_grid.Rows.Add(i,array[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Это код создает новые поля..Но как сделать чтобы значения k,не переносилось на новую строку а дописывалось уже в существующее поле.

Comment: А если через простую конкатенацию строк, попробовать?

Comment: Данные которые в поля нужно добавить хранятся в массиве(List).В массиве по индексу 1 к примеру 27 id,по индексу 2 4id.Так что вряд ли выйдет...

Comment: А Вам нужно чтобы только определенные шли вместе через запятую? или просто последовательно?

Comment: Самособой желательно через запятую,должно ведь быть отделение между id

Comment: @ლუკაბერიანიძე покажите код вашего вывода

Comment: for (int m = 0; m < read.Monsters_count; m++)
            {

                for (int k = 0; k < read.Main[m].count; k++)
                {
                    Npcs_and_mobs_grid.Rows.Add(m + 1, read.Main[m].dops[k].id);

                }
            }

Comment: Это код добавления...Остальное видно по индексам в массивах..